VirtualHost ErrorLog directive is ignored
I have the following VirtualHost config:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com

    ServerAdmin me@company.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/src/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/website/src/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/website/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/website/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

I recently noticed that errors aren't written to error.log. Access information does gets logged in access.log, so it's not a permissions issue with the logs folder. error.log has similar file permissions as access.log. Also if I explicitly set the error_log parameter in php.ini to /var/www/html/website/logs/error.log, then errors are in fact written to the error.log.
If I run apachectl -S I get the following output:

VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   website.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33

The ErrorLog is clearly not what I defined in the ErrorLog directive.
The path it displays points to
# ls -la /var/log/apache2/error.log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 11 Jul  4  2023 /var/log/apache2/error.log -> /dev/stderr

This explains lack of logs, but not why the ErrorLog directive is ignored.
How do I fix this?
